# Accessing Instance Data of Objects within 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I currently am working on a simplified inventory program where I have objects called Items (each have a name, rating, and price) that are stored in Item arrays called Rack, and racks are stored in 2d Rack arrays called warehouseRacks. I need to get the price of the all the items and sum them up.

```
public double totalAssets(){
        double sum = 0.0; 
            for (int i=0; i<warehouseRacks.length; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<warehouseRacks[i].length; j++){
                    Rack racks = warehouseRacks[i][j];
                    Item[] item = racks[i].getItem();
                        sum = sum + thing[j].getPrice();
                    }
                }
            return sum; 
    }
```

I'm having trouble indexing into all of the arrays to get out actual Item object, so I either get errors like the following, or null pointer exceptions.

I'm currently getting this error: Warehouse.java:57: error: array required, but Rack found
                        Item[] thing = racks[i].getItem();

What am I missing that's keeping it from getting out the Item?

*I'm new to Java and have been working with OOP concepts for a week or so!

Comment: As the error implies, `racks[i].getItem()` returns a `Rack` object, that you are trying to assign to a  `Item[]` object .

Comment: you are reading items : Item[] item = racks[i].getItem();   but you do nothing with it?

Comment: the sum line should be 

sum = sum+item[j].getPrice();

Comment: I think you need additional loop on top of sum+item[j].getPrice() to iterate over item , are you sure this give you back array? racks[i].getItem();

Comment: You are at Georgia tech?!?!? let me know if you need private java lessons :)